# Is there a way to look at the inside of a cube or other object?

Tags: objects

Is there any way that you can look at the inside of a cube and edit it from the inside? If so is there a way to see textured faces on the inside of a cube so they aren't transparent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you move the camera inside the cube you can't see the textures because they are hidden if the faces normal (cyan lines starting in the middle of each face) points outward.

In edit-mode you can toggle (with all faces selected ) the normals inside out with the Flip-Directions command.

For the images the top face if the cube was hidden <kbd>H</kbd> and display of normals activated in the properties panel:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much you actually answered me perfectly and taught me another trick in the process. The trick you taught me I was actually going to do in another question. Thanks!

Comment: @GarrettLozano Glad I could help

Comment: Is there anyway I could show both sides of the cube at once? How do you unhide hidden sides?

Comment: <kbd>Alt-H </kbd> unhides

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to use **Clipping Border**.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> to set the border. It will hide anything beyond the border from the original view angle, and show the inside of a mesh object.

[image: 1a]

When finished, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> again to clear the border.

Comment: You answered my question for the most part but the other guy gave me a little bit for info. I will however use both methods so thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's just complementing stacker's answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see inside an object is to hide faces*. The advantage of this technique is that the user can freeform-select the parts of their model that they want to cut away.

1. Select the faces that you want to hide and press <kbd>H</kbd>. You can repeat this step until all the obscuring faces are hidden.
2. To recall all of the hidden faces, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

If you prefer to go through the menu rather than use hotkeys, go to the bottom toolbar and select *Mesh > Show/Hide*.

*This technique was mentioned as part of another answer, but I wanted to clarify its use and provide a complete description.

Comment: When I do this, they become hidden, but once I leave edit mode by pressing tab again, it shows again. And only disappears when I again enter edit mode by pressing tab. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I ended up using mask from here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26704/139373

Answer (score 0):

There are further solutions: press 5(tn) (or go to menu View > view Persp/Ortho) and switch in the view mode from "orthogonal" to "perspective" mode. Then, when you zoom enough you can "enter" into an object as if you were a ghost and you can even move inside it. Very useful for ex. if you design a house and you need to "fly" or "walk" inside it as if you were a virtual person.
You can even use the camera,  animate it as if it was doing a journey inside an object.
It is also possible to use View > Navigation > Fly Navigation (or Walk Navigation): this will switch the view to perspective mode and will allow you to fly/walk throughout the scene using the mouse for direction, wheel to speed up or brake down as needed... Of course you can go into objects too in this mode. At first will be difficult to control the movements but after a while it's kinda of a "flight simulator"... far less evolved and precise but still works.